# Plots are "jagged" for a simple function

Tags: plotting, regions

I have a weird problem with `DensityPlot`, `ContourPlot`, and `Plot3D`.

The function I want to plot is elementary:

```
DensityPlot[((-1 + 8 F^2 - 4 F Sqrt[-1 + 4 F^2]) R)/(8 F^2), {R, F} \[Element] Rectangle[{100, 1}, {1000, 5}]]
```

However, the result is a very jagged one. Same for `ContourPlot`, and `Plot3D`.

The way to get smooth plots is to specify the plot region not with `Rectangle` but with the standard way, like {R, 100, 1000}, {F, 1, 5}.

```
DensityPlot[((-1 + 8 F^2 - 4 F Sqrt[-1 + 4 F^2]) R)/(8 F^2), {R, 100, 1000}, {F, 1, 5}]
```

This gives a smooth plot.

What's happening actually under the hood?

Is there any workaround for the problem when you don't have any other way to represent the plot region other than using some region objects, like `Rectangle`, `Disk`, `Annulus`, etc?

---

Mathematica 13.2.1.0 on Windows11 (64bit)

Answer (score 2):

A usual way to improve a plot by `PlotPoints` and `WorkingPrecision` works, though the execution is slow.

```
DensityPlot[((-1 + 8 F^2 - 4 F Sqrt[-1 + 4 F^2]) R)/(8 F^2), {R, F} \[Element] 
Rectangle[{100, 1}, {1000, 5}],WorkingPrecision -> 20, PlotPoints -> 300]
```

[image]

The result of

```
DensityPlot[((-1 + 8 F^2 - 4 F Sqrt[-1 + 4 F^2]) R)/(8 F^2), {R,   F} \[Element] 
 RegionConvert[Rectangle[{100, 1}, {1000, 5}], "Parametric"],  PlotPoints -> 200, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

is not  better.

Comment: The quality of `DensityPlot[((-1 + 8 F^2 - 4 F Sqrt[-1 + 4 F^2]) R)/(8 F^2), {R, 
   F} \[Element] Annulus[{100, 6}, {1, 5}]]` also leaves much to be desired.

Comment: Far better than the case of `Rectangle`, but still slightly jagged in the Small F region and weird. I suspect these results stem from some internal procedure about How mathematical plots functions within a given area. Maybe depending on where the first `PlotPoints` are set on the plot region. I don't know...

Answer (score -2):

The main problem seems to be the distorted Rectangle!

Try

```
DensityPlot[((-1 + 8 F^2 - 4 F Sqrt[-1 + 4 F^2]) R)/(8 F^2), {R, 100,1000}, {F, 1, 5}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Comment: Did you read "The way to get smooth plots is to specify the plot region not with Rectangle but with the standard way, like {R, 100, 1000}, {F, 1, 5}" and "Is there any workaround for the problem when you don't have any other way to represent the plot region other than using some region objects, like Rectangle, Disk, Annulus, etc?" in the question before having posted it? Can you ground your "The main problem seems to be the distorted Rectangle!"?

Comment: The result of `DensityPlot[((-1 + 8 F^2 - 4 F Sqrt[-1 + 4 F^2]) R)/(8 F^2), {R, 
   F} \[Element] Rectangle[{1, 1}, {10, 5}]]`  is also bad (compare with `DensityPlot[((-1 + 8 F^2 - 4 F Sqrt[-1 + 4 F^2]) R)/(8 F^2), {R, 1, 
  10}, {F, 1, 5}]`) so your speculation  does not correspond to reality.

Comment: Obviously I didn't read the whole question, but my answer seems to be quite smooth. Otherwise, I refrain from further hopeless discussions